# iOS-Error while uploading app to store with facebook integration

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, app-store

I have integrated facebook in my app to upload images to facebook. I have create the app id and completed everything. I can upload my image to the facebook page.

But while uploading my app to the store, I got some issues

> The following URL schemes found in your app are not in correct format:[fb 464863668026]. URL schemes need to begin with an alphabetic character, and be comprised of alphanumeric characters, the period, the hyphen or the plus sign only. Please see RFC1738 for more detail.

Does anybody have an idea what the error is for. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `fb 464863668026` should be `fb464863668026` in your URL scheme

Comment: but I didnt gave anything like this anywer, I have created it in the plist

Comment: Try FB as capitals in the url scheme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Target > select projectName > Select "info" > select url Type > select add (+) button , write your bundle id which you write in fb settings and give URL scheme fb464863668026.

now thats ok

Answer (score 2):

Select you `<Project>-Info.plist`

Then add `FacebookAppID` and `URLTypes` as shown in following screenshot -

[image: info plist screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Target->ProjectName -> Info.plist Preprocessor Definitions -> FB_URL = fb464863668026 and add FB_URL in plist URL Scheme item[0].

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My problem was a leading space.

Just thought I'd post in case anyone else comes across this with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There must be white space in your URL_SCHEMES
Check all Url Types in info.plist and remove any space you find in any url there.
This fixed this issue for me.